# Redirect all files access to a php using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all files access to a php file and this php has to know the file that is trying to be access, currently I have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ valid_user.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it's not working since all files are currently being served ignoring valid_user.php. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that this .htaccess is not on root folder, is on a subfolder.

Comment: Show us the php code you're using?

Comment: For now it only says: print_r($_GET);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have you read [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) and considered if you need `mod_rewrite` for this?

Second, are you sure your Apache configuration permits use of `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I am not sure if I need mod_rewrite, what alternative can I use? How can I know if the Apache config permits use of .htaccess files? I am on a shared host

Comment: If you're not sure if you need `mod_rewrite`, the wiki page I linked will show you options. `mod_redirect` is the most likely option. If you don't know if your config permits `.htaccess` files, ask your sysadmin. If it's a hosting company, they probably have a FAQ for it. (Hosting companies probably *do* permit it, but a paranoid sysadmin may not, or may not have `mod_rewrite` installed.)